# PHP Should I use ob_clean after ob_start

Tags: php, mysql, header, ob-start

I made a simple login-system in php and mysql, but I keep getting errors saying that headers already been sent, and using ob_start fixes this problem, but im not sure if I should then use ob_clean at the footer afterward?

Also, the error comes when I have logged in to the account page, saying header already been sent in previuos page - > header("Location: account.php"); But I have to redirect the user when they login.

My login page looks like this

```
require_once('models/init.php');  // db connection and other functions
include('header.php');  // some html code for the header, with one line php-function to check if user is logged in, if so show "home" tab instead of "login"


{ 

  php code to check if username/pass matches etc, and if so redirect to account page

  header("Location: account.php");

}

 echo "<form>" // display the login form

include("footer"); // including footer, some html/js code.
```

This code above works if I use ob_start in the header.php file. But should I use ob_clean afterwards in the footer.php file?

Sorry if anything is unclear, english is not my first languish

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just place the login check above the `header.php` include?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but I still get a error saying header already output. Also if I do it like that, ob_start fixes the problem even then

Comment: No, best practice would be to remove white space before `header()`.

Comment: Thanks I will keep that in mind, but when using ob_start, should I use ob_clean afterwards eg in the footer? The manual seems a little unclear for me, thats why I am asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general principle is you cannot use `echo` before `header()`. So, this will never work:

```
echo "this is my header";
header("Location: account.php");
echo "this is my footer";
```

However, if you sent the headers first, everything works fine:

```
header("Location: account.php");
echo "this is my header";
echo "this is my footer";
```

In your case, you should do the check before you include the header:

```
require_once('models/init.php');  // db connection and other functions

if ($user_is_logged_in) { // Do your check here
    header("Location: account.php");
}

include('header.php');  // some html code for the header, with one line php-function to check if user is logged in, if so show "home" tab instead of "login"
echo "<form>" // display the login form
include("footer"); // including footer, some html/js code.
```

Comment: This is what I would do, and if you still get the error, make sure there is no whitespace before the first `<?php` and check for [utf-8 `BOM`s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

Comment: Thanks for making it so clear to me, "dont use echo before header()"
In the header.php file I had a if(!isUserLoggedIn()) echo this else echo that.

Comment: Also will accepts your answer, it says I cant do it until 4min

Answer (score 1):

`ob_start()` captures the output (what would otherwise be printed or echoed). If you don't need to echo the output or to do anything with it then just use `ob_end_flush()` when you are finished.